# Select Menu onChange DIV element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to display the `english1` div if 'English' is selected & `french` div if French is selected.

How do I achieve this using Javascript?

```
<form method="get" action="/">
    <fieldset>
<select name='cat' id='cat' class='postform' >
    <option value='0' selected='selected'>Choose one&#8230;</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="english1">English</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="french1">French</option>
</select>
        <script type="text/javascript"><!--
            var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
            function onCatChange() {
                if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value != '0' ) {
                    location.href = "http://localhost:8888/mysite/?language="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
                }
            }
            dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
        --></script> 

    </fieldset>
</form>

<div class="english1">english</div>
<div class="french1">french</div>
```

Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this snippet:

```
$('#cat').change(function(){
 $('form').siblings('div').hide();
 $('.'+$('#cat').val()).show();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sry1tuyo/)**

Comment: I have rebuilt it a little using your code, but it doesn't work just yet: http://jsfiddle.net/m77do3u7/ Any ideas?

Comment: that is because you have not added the code in change event. see the updated answer.

Comment: An excellent point! :-) Is there a way to reset it, so if I select 'English' then back to 'Choose one...' it'll show all the results again?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk: do you want both the divs shown if choose one is selected as option?? like this http://jsfiddle.net/zpymzho8/ ?